# Firefox Quantum ESR PKCS11 - How to Load via script or configuration settings

Tags: firefox, module, pkcs#11

Is there any way to load a PKCS11 module via a script or config on Firefox Quantum ESR?

I've noticed that our smartcard authentication is no longer working since upgrading our environment from firefox 32 bit 38.x.x to Firefox quantum esr 64 bit.

I can manually go into the security devices area and load the PKCS11 module manually. This works.

But I can't expect all of our users to do this manually.

Is there any code or files i can push out to resolve this issue?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at file `pkcs11.txt` in user's profile.

I have just added the module and found this lines inside:

```
library=etpkcs11.dll 
name=eToken PKCS#11 Module
```

If you don't have this file - just create new one with this lines.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. This has resolved my issue. Thanks so much Alexander.

Comment: What if `pkcs11.txt` doesn't exist? Can I just create a new file with this name?

Comment: @FábioRobertoTeodoro I have just corrected my answer.